# Is SecPKCS12Import() available in Monotouch.Security?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, xamarin.ios, pkcs#12

I can't seem to find a way to accomplish what SecPKCS12Import() does in the classes of Monotouch.Security.  Is it wrapped somewhere?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try referencing the Mono.Security assembly and then:

```
using Mono.Security.X509;
[...]
new PKCS12 (byte [] { ... });
// or
PKCS12.LoadFromFile (...)
```